# Remove first occurance of column value from dataframe in r

Tags: r

For the dataframe

```
 first = c(5,11,111,1111,564,877)
 second = c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
  sample <- data.frame(first,second)

  first second
1     5      1
2    11      1
3   111      2
4  1111      2
5   564      3
6   877      3
```

I want to remove first occurance of elements in column2 from dataframe

```
  first second
1    11      1
2  1111      2
3   877      3
```

Comment: Here is a `dplyr` option that uses `slice`: `library(dplyr); sample %>% group_by(second) %>%  slice(-1)`

Comment: original question was framed differently